# Access list property in Realm migration

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-migration

I'm trying to access a `List<String>` property in a migration block.

My database object looks as follows:

```
@objcMembers
public class Foo: Object {
    let bar: List<String> = .init()
}
```

In my migration block I'm trying to access `bar`, but can't seem to get it right:

```
static func migrateFoo(_ migration: RealmSwift.Migration) {
    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Foo.className()) { old, _ in
        let test = old?["bar"] as? List<String>
        let test2 = old?["bar"] as? [String]
        let test3 = old?["bar"]
    }
}
```

Both `test` and `test2` are `nil`. The output of `test3` show the following:

```
(lldb) po test3
▿ Optional<Any>
  - some : List<string> <0x600001fb5f80> (
    [0] someContent
)
```

What would I need to cast `test3` to, to be able to access the list?

**EDIT**

I want to access the element in the `bar` property, hence I thought that casting the migration object's `bar` property to a `List<String>`, which is the data type after all, would be sufficient. In the end what I would like to have is this:

```
for element in test {
    print(element) // `element` should be a `String` here
}
```

Comment: It is possible this stems from primitives being second class citizens in Realm... If possible, try to make a wrapper class with a String property instead.

Comment: @OscarApeland That might be possible. Unfortunately changing the type of `bar` will lead to a lot of other problems :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the full scope is of what your trying to do but a specific answer to the question would be:

```
let test = [ old!["bar"] ]
```

**EDIT**

The OP added some additional information. The goal is to be able to access the values within the bar List property. Here's some quickie code that iterates over that list and outputs the index and the object (as a string) to the console.

```
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Foo.className()) { oldItem, newItem in
    let dynamicBarList = oldItem?.dynamicList("stringList")
    if let list = dynamicBarList {
        let myArray = list._rlmArray
        let lastIndex = myArray.count - 1

        for index in 0...lastIndex {
            let object = myArray.object(at: index)
            let value = "\(object)" //make the NSTaggedPointerString a String
            print(index, value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I want to access the elements in the `bar` property list. With your method I will have wrapped the `Any` object into an array?

Comment: Ah.. ok. Probably need to add a bit more to the question so that's more clear. Wasn't sure what you were doing.. migrating to a new object or just needing to access elements. I'll update shortly.

Comment: My bad, I'll update my question to clarify that as well. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @ShitakeOishii Ok, updated the answer. That will enable you to access the data in the foo list.

Comment: @Jay let supportedDocumentTypes = existingCompanyObject.dynamicList("supportedDocumentTypes")
            let supportedDocumentTypesArray = supportedDocumentTypes._rlmArray
            
            for index in 0...supportedDocumentTypesArray.count - 1  {
                if let value = supportedDocumentTypesArray.object(at: index) as? Int {
...
                }
            }

When accessing supportedDocumentTypesArray.count I get back "Swift runtime failure: arithmetic overflow".
In my case I have a List<Int> that I need to access in migration

Comment: @SerbanS That code is a bit hard to read in comments. Is it possible to create a new question with code and further details? Take a look at the guide so you can properly phrase and format the question [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know once posted and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Jay I have found the issue. In some cases the list was empty and during migration when iterating over the elements, using for index in 0...supportedDocumentTypesArray.count - 1 { ... } caused the runtime overflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your list into a list of DynamicObjects (Object interface which allows untyped getters and setters for Objects):

```
if let old = old?["bar"] as? List<DynamicObject> {
    for i in 0..<old.count {
        let p = old[i]
        print(p) // someContent
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try to give this a go.

Comment: This actually throws an exception: Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x7fff87a8a270) to 'RealmSwift.DynamicObject' (0x10ec94fe8).

Comment: Huh. This is interesting. When I was testing, my list was a collection of RealmObjects, and it had no problem. When I tested with a list of Strings I got the same error. However, if you access the strings via subscript it has no problem...I'm not entirely sure why this is but I'm going to look into it and if I figure it out Ill get back to you. In the meantime I've updated my answer.

Comment: @ShitakeOishii The issue is how Realm handles primitives in Lists. They are kind of second hand citizens so in some cases you're better off creating a class to actually hold the Strings in the list like this; `class MyStringClass: Object { objc dynamic var my_string = "" }` and then store objects of that class in the list. Then the code in this answer will work.